# How to dynamically add rows in between two matching criterias

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet to help track some expenses

Observe the following spreadsheet:

[image]

Basically, what I want to do is the following:

- Box E14 should sum up rows E7:E13
- Box F14 should sum up rows F7:F13
- Box G14 should sum up rows G7:G13
- Box E19 should sum up rows E16:E18

and you get the point for other column sections and rows.

The formula I currently have (saw for E19) is this: `=SUM(INDIRECT("E15:E" & MATCH("Essential Variable Expenses", $A$1:$A, 0) -2 ))`

This works that I can get the specific range somewhat, but it then fails as I add more rows or delete rows. This is because of the "E15:E" in the INDIRECTfunction.

I tried to do something that would dynamically identify the locations of the buckets, do the offsets, and then try to get the address for a regular sum, but I don't think I'm getting it to work:

Here's what I came up with for the Quality of Life section: `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Quality of Life",$A:$A,0),1,4)), 1, 0),$A:$A,0),1,4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Essential Variable Expenses",$A:$A,0),1,4)), -2, 0),$A:$A,0),1,4)))`

Unfortunately, what I have above just returns a 0, despite having values >0 in the category.

To break it apart, `=ADDRESS(MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Quality of Life",$A:$A,0),1,4)), 1, 0),$A:$A,0),1,4)` returns A16

`=ADDRESS(MATCH(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH("Essential Variable Expenses",$A:$A,0),1,4)), -2, 0),$A:$A,0),1,4)` returns A18

I thought I could construct the range arguments for `SUM` one at a time, which why it looks a bit hectic. I feel like I'm so close - how do I get A16 to reference relatively to column E (so E16). Same for A18 (to E18). Same for any other columns

Any insights on what I'm doing wrong? I'm also open to suggestions for a new way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

Here's what I did for the Immediate Expenses section

1. Create a named category "ImmediateExpenses" that covers `6:14`
2. Used the formula in cell E14:

`=SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(index(ImmediateExpenses,0,COLUMN()), rows(ImmediateExpenses)-1, 1))`

Explanation:

1. `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` ignores the last row (which is the total amount row). This is done with `rows(ImmediateExpenses)-1)`. I had it in such a way that I can insert a new row at the way bottom without screwing up the Name Range's range. Sheets will automatically update that for me
2. `Index(...)` grabs the entirety of the Named Range and then filters it on the current column only

Also will need to enable circular calculation and set the max iterations to 1